# Solr SolrCore Initialization Failures {{Core}}: {{error}}

Tags: solr, sitecore

All, 
I am trying to install Solr 7.2.1. While the installation works, i am not able to run solr successfully. Whenever i try to run, i get the following error.

> SolrCore Initialization Failures {{core}}: {{error}}
>
> Please check your logs for more information
>   [image]

I am not sure exactly what the error is. i dont see anything in the logs either. all i see are are some info. 
[image]
Please advice.

> cmd solr.cmd start
>
> or cmd solr.cmd stop -p 8983

doesn't have any issues. 
i am running solr in 8982 port instead of the usual 8983. not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: According to the log it seems like you've shut down your Solr instance - and you're still refering to port 8983 when shutting down?

Comment: @MatsLindh that screen shot is probably a bad example. i was restarting the service to see if that fixes the problem and sent the log of that .  i updated a log with clean install. dont see that as problem. i am able to install it fine in my local machine which is windows 10 vs the server being windows 2016. not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: From your screenshots I'm guessing the javascript interface isn't working at all. It seems like you're using Internet Explorer, which is probably not supported - try a different browser first.

Comment: @MatsLindh you are right. i had this figured out. but your answer is spot on. IE was not allowing Javascript and since it is a sever i wasnt allowd to download any other browers. i had to "Enable Scripts" in IE setting and that worked.

Comment: A good spot re IE, @NightMonger! You can run Solr on any port, there is no restrictions. Just note that if Solr console loads with an error then it doesn't mean that Solr itself is not working.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by others, this problem is related to the javascript interface not related to the solr server. The same thing happened to me in Chrome. **Clearing the site data** worked for me. 
Clear site data by opening developer tools and going to `Application -> clear storage`
[image: clear cache]

#### Important Note:

The usage was 0B before and after clearing the site data but after clearing the site data solr home page came up without any error.

Comment: And also don't forget to force reload the page without cache( In mac with Shift key)

Comment: I lost many hours to debugging this going through the logs etc. You have my thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

CTRL + F5 did the trick for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the IE only, I have faced the same error. There was nothing in the logs as well. I finally Enabled the JavaScript for IE, Closed all the browser instance and tried again. And it is working perfectly fine for me.

Please refer below image for the reference.

[image]